# Enumerating directed graph nodes

Tags: graph-theory, heuristics

Let's say I have a directed graph with relatively few edges (e.g. `N` = 1000 nodes, `M` = 3000 edges). I need to enumerate the nodes from 1 to `N`, so that as few edges as possible are directed from a lower numbered node to a higher numbered one.

For example, this is a good edge:

```
44 o----------->o 12
```

And this one is bad:

```
 3 o------------> 117
```

How would I even approach this problem? I suppose there are existing algorithms for such tasks, but don't know what to search for. Also, I don't need to find the absolutely best solution, just something that is close enough in practice. E.g. if global best is 5 bad edges, a solution with 10 bad edges is good enough for my purposes too (but 200 is not).

Answer (score 0):

Especially since you only want a good solution and not necessarily the best, it sounds like a Markov Chain Monte Carlo method should work for you.

1. Start with a random enumeration E_0 of the nodes and calculate your score S(E_0)
2. For many steps

   - Every time step j, obtain a new enumeration candidate E* from the current E_j by changing the numbers of two nodes.
   - Calculate the score S(E* ). (Don't completely calculate it new but from S(E_j) by regarding only the two nodes you changed and the edges they are involved in)
   - Change E_j to E* if S(E* ) <= S(E_j).
   - If S(E* )>S(E_j) still change E_j to E_* with a positive
     probability, f.e. (S(E_j)/S(E_*))^k where k influences how
     strongly you want your algorithm to penalize bad choices.

While running this algorithm, keep track of the lowest score obtained and the enumeration that achieved it.

Answer (score 0):

You necessarily have edges comming from cycles, so you'll first want to decompose your problem into [strongly connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component).

Note that the graph of your strongly connected components is acyclic, meaning two nodes from different components are easy to compare.

Then, you can probably try to search for cycles and "mark bad" one edge in each cycle, which will transform your components into DAG themselves (you can try removing edges common to a lot of cycles, this should help).

I have to admit I have no idea how this would behave in matter of bad edges, but I think it would be quite a good approach.

Comment: At least the first step is certainly useful. About the second, how would I determine if an edge is part of several cycles?

Comment: I don't know, enumerating the cycles would be costly so I guess I would try to find the smaller ones first, the redundant edges are probably in those.